# Is it possible to skip visibility checks when generating dynamic IL with MethodBuilder's?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

When generating IL using DynamicMethod it's possible to call methods and access fields that would be otherwise un-accessible if you provide 'true' for the restrictedSkipVisibility parameter in the [DynamicMethod constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348332.aspx)

I would prefer to emit dynamic IL into a dynamic assembly instead so I can save the generated IL into an assembly at build time. If I use this method I have to use a MethodBuilder instead of a DynamicMethod. However I need to be able to skip visibility checks so I don't get MethodAccessException's when I run my dynamic code. Is there a way to do this and if so how?

Comment: Is this problem solved? Can you briefly described how you solved it?

Comment: No. As far as I can tell it isn't solvable. I ended up taking another approach to the solution by using the Mono.Cecil library to re-write the assembly. This way I could access private or internal members without violating type-safety rules. However, with that method I was un-able to get the symbols to match correctly to source files which caused other annoyances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using MethodBuilder into a dynamic assemblies, you are bound to the same rules as the compiler generated assemblies. So, inter-assembly visibility is governed by:

- The [ReflectionPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.reflectionpermission.aspx) attribute.
- The [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute.

Please read the documentation and the samples, to see if it could fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to materialize your generated code by interface instead of delegate, il will be usefull to skipVisibilityCheck for a Methodbuilder. I did not find a way to do it directly, but you can simple call a DynamicMethod in your MethodBuilder by using EmitCalli(OpCodes.Calli...).